# Errors while installing sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pip, pycharm

I've been trying to install sklearn manually using pip with python 3.6 and i'm facing a lot of trouble. I couldn't get it installed cuz there was a problem with scipy. 
I installed pycharm and tried to install both of them using the Packages interfaces and i'm still getting an error while trying to install sklearn.
[image]

NB: I installed scipy and numpy+mkl using their whl files

Comment: try `pip3 install`?

Comment: try `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: It looks you are using anaconda, so use anaconda's ```conda installer```. Not sure what you mean by using whl-files. Stick to using ```conda install X``` for everything available, and ```pip install Y``` for the rest. Don't mix this with other binary-sources (which calls for trouble)! Example: after installing anaconda, numpy and scipy are already there and ```conda install scikit-learn``` should never fail (on this clean system) Assumption: sklearn is not part of anaconda by default which i'm not sure.

Comment: Try uninstalling anaconda

Comment: @sascha I have just resolved it, What I meant by using whl-files is that I was downloading, let's say the whl file of numpy and then pip install that file. I did that for scipy too. But for scikit-learn I tried pip install sklearn n' apparently it generated some conflict. So I downloaded the whl file of scikit-learn too and installed it the same way as the other files and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The module name is `scikit-learn`, not `sklearn`.